# Number of vectors in a span over a certain field

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $S = \{u_1, u_2,\ldots, u_n\}$ be linearly independent subset of vector space $V$ over $\mathbb Z_2$. Number of vectors in $\operatorname{span}(S)$?

Consider $u_1 + u_2 + \cdots + u_n \in \operatorname{span}(S)$. There are $n$ ways to rearrange $u_1 + u_2 + \cdots + u_n$. For example, $u_2 + u_1 + \cdots + u_n$ or $u_n + u_2 + \cdots + u_1$. There are two scalars - $0, 1$ - to multiply every permutation of $u_1 + u_2 + \cdots + u_n$. So, in all there are $2^n$ vectors in the span. Does that make sense?

edit: the number of rearrangements of elements in the span looks wrong. I'd still be interested in a hint.

Comment: You got the right idea: for each $j$, we choose $0$ or $1$, multiply $u_j$, and add all of these elements. This gives of $span(S)$. Since there are $2^n$ choices of $0$ and $1$, $span(S)$ has at most $2^n$ elements. However we need to show that there are *exactly* $2^n$ elements, and for this we use linear independence. If you want to be formal, show that the function $\Phi:\left\{0,1\right\}^{\{1,\ldots,n\}}\to span(S)$, where $\{0,1\}^S=\{\text{functions }f:\{1,\ldots,n\}\to\{0,1\}\}$, $\Phi(f)=\sum_{j=1}^nf(j)u_j$, is a bijection, and use the fact that there are $2^n$ such functions $f$.

Comment: There are $2$ possibilities for $u_1$, another $2$ for $u_2 \ldots$ Altogether, $2^n$ elements. How do we know all their sums equal $2^n?$ Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the answer is $2^n$, but your reasoning is a bit off. First off, vector spaces are commutative under addition, so the elements you say are different, actually aren't. There is no need to consider rearrangements.

The reason why I say $2^n$ is because take $s \in \text{span }S$. Then 
$$s = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i u_i.$$
So you have two choices for each $a_i$, namely $1$ or $0$. Since there are $n$ elements, with two choices each, you have $2^n$ elements.

Comment: I am having a brainfart moment. There are two choices for $a_1u_1,$ another two for $a_2u_2, \ldots,$ two more possibilities for $a_nu_n.$ So the number of $a_iu_i$ is $2^n$. Does that make sense? How does summing over the terms enter this whole thing? Thanks.

Comment: @user342340 Writing $s$ as that sum is just the definition of $s$ being in the span of $S$. Namely, $s$ can be written as a linear combination of the elements in $S$. So in determining what $s$ could possibly be, you need to consider the coefficients, the $a_i$'s. There are two choices for each $a_i$. Sine there are $n$ coefficients to choose, this gives you a total of $2^n$ distinct choices of coefficients.

Comment: @ user332239   Consider an arbitrary element $a_1u_1 + a_2u_2 + \ldots + a_nu_n$ in the span. Since there are $2^n$ ways to choose $a_i$ then  there are as many ways to modify  $a_1u_1 + a_2u_2 + \ldots + a_nu_n$. All these $2^n$ different forms of $a_1u_1 + a_2u_2 + \ldots + a_nu_n$, then, are in the span. Correct?

Comment: @user342340 I'm not sure what you mean by modify? But, each choice of the $a_i$'s gives a unique element in the span.

Comment: @ user332239. I meant $ a_1u_1 + a_2u_2 + \ldots + a_nu_n$ could be uniquely represented by $2^n$ choices of $a_i$. Yeah, wrong term to use :)